# file.exists() returns true even though I know it's not there Android

Tags: java, android

I am completely re-jigging this question.

Using :

```
File latestNumbersFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/" + (Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS + getString(R.string.dloaded_latest_numbers_dir) + getString(R.string.dloaded_latest_numbers_file)));
```

as the file location I can do a :

```
boolean fileWasRemoved = latestNumbersFile.getAbsoluteFile().delete();
```

and the file gets deleted. I can confirm that using Android File Manager and actually look for myself.

But when I do :

```
boolean fileExists = latestNumbersFile.exists();

        if (fileExists = true) {
            fileExist.setText("File Exists!");
        } else {
                if (fileExists = false)
                    fileExist.setText("File Does Not Exists!");
            }
```

I ALWAYS get `true`

This code is in the same method.

Can anyone shed some light on this?

Comment: Real device or simulator? Is the file on the internal memory or the SD card (or somewhere else)?

Comment: Real device, latest Android OS file is in the default Downloads dir in internal memory. So File Commander shows it as "Internal Storage/Download/MyDir"

Comment: Yes, the file is always there if I download it, but if I delete it and don't download again I still get `true` for `file.exists()`

Comment: it should be (file==true) hope it s not printing mistake

Comment: @Sania I am such a noob! Thanks for pointing that out. You are absolutly right! Was my problem all along!

Comment: it s ok .sometym happens.@Ash

Answer (score 0):

As @Meghna points out

```
 if (fileExists = true) {
```

is an *assignment* (not a comparison) and always returns true.

Should be

```
if (fileExists) {
```